# how can i have scrollbar when position is negative?

Tags: css, scrollbar

When position is positive, scrollbar work just fine. but when left is negative, scrollbar won't apear. how can i have scrollbar when element is on the left side or on the right side?

sample is here:

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    background: gray;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    top : 200px;
    left: -50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **'how can i have scrollbar when element is on the left side or on the right side'**?

Comment: look at the sample please. when left: -50px no horizontal scrollbar. but when it's left: 250px scrollbar appears. top property act the same.

Comment: overflow-x: scroll; will always show a scroll bar, but I'm not 100% sure if this is what you want. it sounds like you want to be able to scroll to a minus position, but I don't think that is possible

Comment: it's show scrollbar but it's not active. i want to scroll to a minus position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you cannot do that, because the browsers do not provide that feature.

This is my understanding after looking at the WebDriver spec
http://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html

In the section titled 'Determining if an element is displayed'

there is a point that says 
"The User Agent must not allow negative scrolling"