# CSS Transform Translate: Can't scroll into translated area

Tags: css, scroll, transformation, translate

I've got a viewport fixed in size (blue rectangle in illustration). Within this viewport I've got my content. Whenever the content is greater in size than the surrounding viewport, I want to be able to scroll. This so far works just fine.

The problem I'm experiencing comes into play as soon as I transform my content. Let's say I want to scale and translate it in order to show a certain area in higher detail.
After this transformation I still want to be able to reach every corner of my content with the scrollbars of the viewport (green in illustration). But I can only croll right and down. Everything above and left of my translation can't be reached with the scrollbars.

[image: Illustration of viewport and content]

Is this just how things are, or am I missing something? Is there a good solution to this?

Comment: Can you add some code.

Comment: Good image, it explains the problem perfectly. The thing with transforms is that the element's bounding box won't change, so the browser doesn't really know there's more up there. You could try and set the transform-origin property to 0,0; although I think for something like this (zooming and panning) using <canvas> would be a better approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i have scrollbar when position is negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374111/how-can-i-have-scrollbar-when-position-is-negative)